# How to interpret si_status value

Tags: linux, perl, signals

I am working with perl signal handler function for SIGCHLD signal handler on Ubuntu system. 
In order to get sa_siginfo I am unpacking binary data I get from sigaction.Now I am getting si_code as "25". Looking at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html how to interpret that? It says it is not bitmask but a value. 
Output I am getting is :

```
in order : signo sicode sigval sigerro sigpid siuid siaddr sistatus siband 17 0 1 0 21225 0 0 25 0
```

Signo,pid are unpacked correctly, I verified.I do not understand how I get 25 as "si_status"

```
POSIX::sigaction(
    POSIX::SIGCHLD,
    POSIX::SigAction->new(
        sub{
         my $args = \@_;
         my $pid = unpack "x16S",$_[2];
         my($signo,$sicode,$sigval,$sigerro,$sipid,$siuid,$siaddr,$sistatus,$siband) = unpack "iiiiisssii" ,$_[2];
         print "\n in order : signo sicode sigval sigerro sigpid siuid siaddr sistatus siband ";
         print (join (" ", $signo, $sicode , $sigval , $sigerro  ,$sipid  ,$siuid  ,$siaddr  ,$sistatus  ,$siband));
          }
          0,
          POSIX::SA_SIGINFO ),
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `si_status` (not `si_code`) that's `25`.

> The `si_status` field contains the exit status of the child (if `si_code` is `CLD_EXITED`), or the signal number that caused the process to change state.

If `si_code` is `CLD_EXITED`, the child exited normally with exit code `si_status`.

If `si_code` is `CLD_KILLED`, the child was killed by signal `si_status`.

---

There are a few errors in your unpacking. They are fixed in the following, and it shows how to interpret `si_status`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );
use POSIX qw( CLD_EXITED );

my $done;

sub sig_child {
    my ($signo, $errno, $code, $trapno, $pid, $uid, $status) =
        unpack("iiiiiii", $_[2]);

    print("$signo $errno $code $trapno $pid $uid $status\n");

    if ($code == CLD_EXITED) {
        if ($status) {
            print("Process $pid exited with error $status\n");
        } else {
            print("Process $pid completed successfully\n");
        }
    } else {
        print("Process $pid was killed by signal $status\n");
    }

    $done = 1;
}

POSIX::sigaction(
    POSIX::SIGCHLD,
    POSIX::SigAction->new(\&sig_child, 0, POSIX::SA_SIGINFO),
);

sub test {
    $done = 0;
    no warnings qw( once );
    open(local *CHILD_STDIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die($!);
    open3('<&CHILD_STDIN', '>&STDOUT', '>&STDERR', @_);
    sleep(1) while !$done;
}

test('perl', '-e', 'exit(123)');
test('perl', '-e', 'kill(TERM => $$)');
```

Output:

```
17 0 1 0 24351 2268518 123
Process 24351 exited with error 123
17 0 2 0 24352 2268518 15
Process 24352 was killed by signal 15
```

Comment: Thanks :) .. I think I got confused between si_code and si_status. the man page says it is exit code of the child.

Comment: No, that's not what the man page says at all, and I already showed it can return something other than the exit code. The man page actually says the same thing I did. See my updated my answer, which corrects a few errors in your unpacking in addition to quoting the man page and showing how to interpret `si_status`.